# Level sets under heat flow

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series, heat-equation

Let $f\in C^\infty([0,2\pi])$ be a smooth periodic function with mean zero ($\int f = 0$).  Let $f(t,x)$ be the heat flow of $f(x)$, so that $f(t,x)$ solves
$$
\partial_t f = f''.
$$
Given a small $\varepsilon>0$, define the approximate zero set
$$
Z_\varepsilon(t) = \{x\in[0,2\pi] \mid |f(t,x)|\leq \varepsilon\}.
$$ 
Is it the case that the measure of $Z_\varepsilon$ is monotone?  That is, does it hold that
$$
|Z_\varepsilon(t)| \leq |Z_\varepsilon(t')|
$$
when $t<t'$?

If it is not monotone, how may one construct a counterexample?